# Qt 5.5.0: difference from Win8 version from Linux Version?

Tags: c++, qt

After install QT 5.5.0 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (launching the downloaded file "qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.5.0-2.run"), first thing I tried to compile one of the enclosed examples. Days ago I installed the same Qt 5.5.0 on Win8: here no problem occurs.
In Ubuntu no example runs.
I checked the kit for build&run and all seems ok.
Is there a difference installing the mentioned file instead of the tar.gz version as I made in the previous 4.8.6?
Further suggestion?

Comment: What's the error message? probably your executable in linux does not find Qt libraries that are in custom folder.

Comment: `In Ubuntu no example runs` - does compilation succeed? What happens when you launch the executable?

Comment: For example, if I try "analogclock" example, error arises is "rasterwindow.h: No such file or directory".
It seems include files have a unknown path or something like this...